# Preserving Encapsulation

Tags: java

In order to preserve encapsulation of an object, we would do all of the following except for 
which one?

A) Make the instance data private

B) Define the methods in the class to access and manipulate the instance data

C) Make the methods of the class public

D) Make the class final

E) All of the above preserve encapsulation

When I saw this question, I thought the answer was C as it says to make **the** methods public. This implies that if methods were private, they would be turned public and therefore not preserve encapsulation. The answer however is D, for the reason that: The reserved word "final" is used to control inheritance and has nothing to do with encapsulation. I do not see how this explanation makes sense, as making methods that were previously private now public wouldn't preserve encapsulation. Can someone explain to me why the right answer is D?

Comment: Encapsulation only refers to variables only being accessible through methods instead of through direct access. Therefore, A and B are what are required. Note that protected instance data would work too.

D is silly - All that does is make the class un-subclassable. You can easily make a final class that doesn't encapsulate an object. If someone is telling you that's the correct answer ... they're wrong.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good question (the one you are referring to, not yours) and the “correct” answer is even worse.

Comment: @SteveB. The question was which one is *not* correct.  However, I think it's still a poor question.

Comment: The question is unanswerable.  If either A, B, C or D is false, then E is also false.  So either zero answers are false, or two (or maore) are false.  But the Question says to identify the *single* false answer.  This is a logical impossibility.

Comment: Combine that with @Steve B's comments, and the only conclusion we can draw is that this is a really bad question.

Comment: The worst part of this is that encapsulation is a simple and clear idea. Why do people take things like this and complicate them? It takes serious work to make this an incomprehensible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E and D conflict as was mentioned. D is correct (We wouldn't do it).
According to E: I think that choice is not regarding the question (It's not "We would't do all of the above, to preserve encapsulation", its the opposite - "All of the above - preserve encapsulation" which is false and not related to the question therefore D is correct.